# Dynamic height not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add height to a div dynamically by calculating header div height and footer div height, but it's not working, Here is the example of the code:

I am looking to handle in pure javascript, no JQuery

```js
function contentHeight(e){
  var winH = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var headerH = document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0];
  var footerH = document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0];
  var contentHei = winH - headerH.clientHeight - footerH.clientHeight;
  document.getElementsByClassName('content-inner')[0].clientHeight = contentHei + "px";
}
contentHeight();
```

```html
<div class="header">
    this is content of header
</div>
<div class="content-inner">
    <!-- Apply dynamic height to this div by calculating header and footer height -->
</div>
<div class="footer">
    footer content
</div>
```

Comment: Do some basic debugging. Do the values of the variables you're assigning contain what you think they do?

Comment: im pretty sure `clientHeight` is read only, have you tried `height`?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I tried height as well but was getting error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `style.height` in order to adjust the height of an element using JS

```js
function contentHeight(e){
  var winH = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var headerH = document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0];
  var footerH = document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0];
  var contentHei = winH - headerH.clientHeight - footerH.clientHeight;
  document.getElementsByClassName('content-inner')[0].style.height = contentHei + "px";
}
contentHeight();
```

```css
body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    this is content of header
</div>
<div class="content-inner">
    <!-- Apply dynamic height to this div by calculating header and footer height -->
</div>
<div class="footer">
    footer content
</div>
```

By the way I suspect you want your content to take the free left space of the screen and you can easily do this with pure CSS.

Here is an idea with flexbox:

```css
body {
 margin:0;
 height:100vh;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column
}

.content-inner {
  flex:1; /*Fill the empty space*/
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    this is content of header
</div>
<div class="content-inner">
    
</div>
<div class="footer">
    footer content
</div>
```